# How can I configure the Jib Extension inside a buildSrc kotlin file?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, jib

I'm trying to modularize my `build.gradle.kts`. It was suggested to me to create a `buildSrc` folder.
After some research and som asking I found this article [I hated Gradle!...](https://quickbirdstudios.com/blog/gradle-kotlin-buildsrc-plugin-android/) so this was my try:

`buildSrc` tree:

```
buildSrc/
├── build.gradle.kts
├── settings.gradle.kts
└── src
    └── main
        ├── kotlin
        │   ├── Docker.kt
        │   ├── MyProjectExtensions.kt
        │   └── Versions.kt
        └── resources
            └── META-INF
                └── gradle-plugins
                    └── pt.branden.brandenportal.properties
```

My `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
    id("com.google.cloud.tools.jib") version Versions.jib
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("gradle.plugin.com.google.cloud.tools:jib-gradle-plugin:${Versions.jib}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50")
    implementation(gradleApi())
    implementation(localGroovy())
}
```

And finally `Docker.kt`:

```
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project


open class JibConfigPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(target: Project) {
        //configureJib()
        TODO("not implemented")
    }

}

//internal fun Project.configureJib() = this.extensions.getByType<JibExtension>().run {}
internal fun Project.configureJib() = project.configure<JibExtension>() {
  TODO("not implemented")
}
```

My problem is that I can't find the `JibExtension`, so when I try to implement and configure the Jib it doesn't work but in the `build.gradle.kts` everything works.

Comment: I though I had the right dependencyNotation, but unfortunately no. So my question is how can I find the right dependencyNotation to put in the implementation function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My problem is that I can't find the `JibExtension`

Plugins or extensions can be applied in a variety of different ways. You can "react" to the plugin being applied by using the [withPlugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginManager.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginManager:withPlugin(java.lang.String,%20org.gradle.api.Action)) method of `PluginManager`:

```
class JibConfigPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.pluginManager.withPlugin("com.google.cloud.tools.jib") {
            // Configuration happens inside this Action block.
        }
    }
}
```

Using this method you can be certain that a plugin exists/has been applied without forcing a user/project to use the plugin.

The Jib plugin offers a single extension and a variety of tasks.

Configuring the extension can be done with the following:

```
class JibConfigPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.pluginManager.withPlugin("com.google.cloud.tools.jib") {
           project.extensions.configure<JibExtension> {
                // Example configuring the `container`
                container {
                    creationTime = "USE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
                }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Looking over [the source](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/jib-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/tools/jib/gradle/JibPlugin.java) of the Gradle plugin for Jib, the authors used [lazy configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html) for the tasks, so it is best to also use the same method to configure those tasks.

For example, to configure the `jib` task:

```
class JibConfigPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.pluginManager.withPlugin("com.google.cloud.tools.jib") {
            project.tasks.named<BuildImageTask>("jib") {
                to {
                    setTargetImage("my_acr_name.azurecr.io/my-app")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above uses the [`named`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskCollection.html#named-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-org.gradle.api.Action-) method which returns a [`TaskProvider`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskProvider.html)

Then simply apply your plugin as documented here: https://guides.gradle.org/writing-gradle-plugins/#apply_the_plugin_to_the_host_project

---

Source of the `build.gradle.kts` I used to test:

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("gradle.plugin.com.google.cloud.tools:jib-gradle-plugin:1.7.0")
}
```